# Unable to connect with google VM via browser SSH

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am unable to connect with my Virtual Machine via browser ssh after upgrading to custom-1-2816.
please see the error message [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P1Va.png)

Troubleshooting tool gives [no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70JCo.png).

When trying to connect from from local system via ssh and google cloud shell, i got the exception

`Permission denied (publickey).  ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].`

For other instances, I don't face any issues while connecting with browser ssh / Google shell  ssh

Comment: Add more details to your post such as [serial console logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console) for us to better understand the issue. Also, when using cloud shell add  `--verbosity=debug` parameter for a more detailed error message.